# Problema de llaves al hacer una migracion

Tags: laravel, migration

[image: imagen de error al hacer la migracion]

aqui les dejo mi migración de products, en la imagen anterior les dejo el error que me da al realizar la migracion pero no entiendo el problema entre las llaves que me indica allí

agradeceria quien me pueda guiar para resolver el problema

estoy haciendo migraciones de los modelos existentes pero no entiendo por que el problema

aqui les dejo el codigo de la migracion de users, para verificar si lo necesitan, y se pueda ubicar el error, es la primera que se ejecuta y se crea en la base de datos, pero al crear la tabla de products me lanza el error que les ubique en la imagen

si me pueden ubicar o guiar donde encontrar el error, esta migracion es la primera que se ejecuta asi que no encuentro o no ubico el problema, en el codigo agradezco su ayuda

se agregan todos los campos que necesito crear para seguir con el proyecto me

---

```
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description', 1000);
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->string('status')->default(Product::PPRODUCTO_NO_DISPONIBLE);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
''
--------------------------------------------------

     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->string('verified')->default(User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO);
            $table->string('verifcation_token')->nullable();
            $table->string('admin')->default(User::USUARIO_REGULAR);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: es la primera que se ejecuta

Comment: debajo de la migracion de products agregue el de users

Comment: en las migraciones primero se ejecuta users, y luego products

Answer (score 0):

La referencia id no la esta encontrando ya que en tus migraciones no has llamado id a nada, deberias cambiar las migraciones asi:

```
$table->id(); a esto-> $table->increments('id');
```

Y ya deberia de funcionar, corre el siguiente comando para deshacer las migraciones que desees donde X es el numero de migraciones hacia atras que quieres explulsar de tu base de datos:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=X
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis que manejas es [correcta](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations), pero aclarando si te encuentras manejando Laravel 7.x.x.

Solo haría falta un detalle:

Las llaves primarias ahora Laravel las asume como **`bigIncrements`** dado eso tus tipos de datos no coinciden.

Debería alcanzar con hacer este cambio.

Pasa está línea

```
$table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
```

A esto

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('seller_id');
```

En caso de que uses una versión inferior de Laravel entonces tu llave primaria debe declararse así

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```